# no incoming messages shown on my mail box

Tags: sms

My phone shows no incoming messages on my mail box icon.

the mailbox icon on my home screen, doesn't show incoming messages ( in the red circle)
please help.

Comment: Is it used to show bubbles before? Not all applications support notification bubbles...

Answer (score 1):

You don't indicate a specific version or email type (Gmail has a distinct solution), so I will recommend this article from Abhinaya Prabhu at Gadgets To Use.

[Enabling Unread email Count Display](http://gadgetstouse.com/gadget-tech/gmail-unread-count-android/21768)